# Function has not been declared

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to call a function from a button but when i press the button it is saying that no function of that name has not been declared.

This is my code for the button:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateOutTxt" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox><asp:ImageButton
                    ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" ImageUrl="~/icons/vwicn063.gif"
                    OnClientClick="PopupPicker(DateOutTxt, 250, 250);" Width="21px" /></td>
```

and here is the function i am trying to call:

```
<script language ="javascript" type ="text/javascript">
    function PopupPicker(ctl, w, h) {
        var PopupWindow = null;
        settings = 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',location=no,directories=no, menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,dependent=no';
        PopupWindow = window.open(<%= getServerName.getserverName("/Quoteman/DatePicker.aspx?Ctl=") %>);
    PopupWindow.focus();
}
</script>
```

I currently have the script tags at the bottom of the  tags, but i have tried putting it in the  tag and below the  tag. I cannot seem to find the problem.

The languages are ASP.Net and Javascript. there is also a call to a VB.Net function in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure avaiability of script, put script in head tag or befor html element being rendered. You are passing the current object in the wrong way, use this instead of DateOutTxt

Change

```
OnClientClick="PopupPicker(DateOutTxt, 250, 250);"
```

To

```
OnClientClick="PopupPicker(this, 250, 250);"
```

Put scriptlet in window.open in quotes.

```
function PopupPicker(ctl, w, h) {
    var PopupWindow = null;
    settings = 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',location=no,directories=no, menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,dependent=no';
    PopupWindow = window.open('<%= getServerName.getserverName("/Quoteman/DatePicker.aspx?Ctl=") %>');
    PopupWindow.focus();
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the error message 'Javascript Runtime Error : PopupPicker is undefined

Comment: Check my updated answer, and remove all code from PopupPicker and put an alert(""); to make sure we can call it.

Comment: can you call this function with firebug?

Comment: it is calling it now but it is opening in another window and wont let me click anything to input data into the textbox that i want to. Thank you ... that solved my problem but now i have another ... ohwell, time for another question.